# when I “import nltk” show selectSelector error

Tags: python, nltk, selector

```
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/hexialong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from nltk.internals import config_java
  File "/Users/hexialong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 11, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/Users/hexialong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 138, in <module>
    import selectors
  File "/Users/hexialong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 290, in <module>
    class SelectSelector(_BaseSelectorImpl):
  File "/Users/hexialong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 317, in SelectSelector
    _select = select.select
AttributeError: module 'select' has no attribute 'select'
```

My environment is MacOS and python version is 3.6

Comment: add that info by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52256451/edit) rather than posting it as comments

Comment: What is the output of `import os; os.listdir('.')`?

Answer (score 0):

`select` is a Python standard module. Maybe you should check that your `python` binaries are unbroken or just reinstall it.
Check that:
`import select` and `select.select` in Python Interactive Environment. If some errors generated, you'd better reinstall the `python` binaries.

Comment: it seems that when I import select ,it works . thank you very much!

Comment: lol, you can choose my answer as correct answer then this question will be labeled solved.